# Equivalent of np.multiply.at in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch, numpy-ufunc

Are there equivalent of np.multiply.at in **Pytorch**? I have two 4d arrays and one 2d index array:

```
base = torch.ones((2, 3, 5, 5))
to_multiply = torch.arange(120).view(2, 3, 4, 5)
index = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 4, 2], [0, 3, 3, 2]])
```

As shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143788/numpy-multidimensional-indexing-for-np-ufunc-at-and-np-ix) I asked earlier (in Numpy), the row index of the index array corresponds to the 1st dimension of base and to_multiply, and the value of the index array corresponds to the 3rd dimension of base. I want to take the slice from base according to the index and multiply with to_multiply, it can be achieved in Numpy as follows:

```
np.multiply.at(base1, (np.arange(2)[:,None,None],np.arange(3)[:,None],index[:,None,:]), to_multiply)
```

However, now when I want to translate this to PyTorch, I cannot find an equivalent of np.multiply.at in Pytorch, I can only find the "index_add_" method but there is no "index_multiply". And I want to avoid doing explicit for loop.

So how can I achieve above in PyTorch? Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else have same question, found the solution: the torch-scatter package has a scatter_mul that does exactly this: https://pytorch-scatter.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.0/functions/mul.html

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584479/3337089

Comment: depending on the values you actually plan to multiply, and the precision you need, you could always take the log first, then apply index_add, then exponentiate the result.